# Try, except - not entering if statement

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x

I have code which I am trying to validate, however it won't enter the `if` statement:

```
while True:
    try:
        ISBN = int(input("Please enter a 10 digit number: "))
        print("TT")
        if len(ISBN)!= 10:
            print("T")
            print("That was an incorrect input.")
        else:
            # do code
    except:   
        print("RRRRR")
        print("That was an incorrect input.")
```

Here is the input/output:

```
Please enter a 10 digit number: 1234567898
TT
RRRRR
That was an incorrect input.
Please enter a 10 digit number:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` objects don't have a length:

```
>>> len(1234567890)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Because you are using a Pokemon exception handler (catching them all) you don't get to have a proper error message telling you this either. Remove your `try:` / `except:` or at the very least narrow it down to one or two exception types you want to ignore; for `int()` conversions, catch *only* `ValueError`. Do so only for the `int()` call, not everything else:

```
while True:
    try:
        ISBN = int(input("Please enter a 10 digit number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("That was an incorrect input.")
    else:
        # continue with ISBN being a valid integer
```

If you want to know the number of digits, either take the length of the *string* version:

```
if len(str(isbn)) != 10:
```

or test for boundaries:

```
if not (10**10 > isbn >= 10**9):
```

Either works to validate a number of 10 digits:

```
>>> isbn = 1234567898
>>> len(str(isbn))
10
>>> (10**10 > isbn >= 10**9)
True
```

Comment: i have tried this: len(str(ISBN))!= 10. but it is still not entering the if statement

Comment: @user3165683: well, no, because in your example you entered a number of 10 digits.

Comment: sorry i dont understand

Comment: There could be other errors too, of course. Did you replace `except:` with `except ValueError:` yet?

Comment: No, i tried that and it gave me a error, but i think that is irreverent as its still not entering the if statement.

Comment: I suspect the error is *very* relevant. What was the error?

Comment: sorry that was just a spelling error, however when i enter this: ISBN()
Please enter a 10 digit number: 1234567898
TT
TTT
Please enter a 10 digit number:                                                                    U see it still doesnt enter the if statment! and that is with the except ValueError change.

Comment: @user3165683: But `1234567898` *is ten digits*. You only enter the `if` statement if the number is **not** ten digits.

Comment: Sorry, error on my part, I meant that it doesn't enter the else (where the code is) either

Comment: @user3165683: I cannot reproduce your problem though. If your `if` statement is not being wrapped in a blanket `try` / `except` then *either* an exception is thrown *or* one of the `if` or the `else` branches is executed. There are no other options.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting `ISBN` input to `int`, and then checking its length.

Change that to

```
ISBN = input("Please enter a 10 digit number: ")
```

and convert it to integer value later in your `else` block.

Note that `int` objects don't have a length, and hence your code directly goes to the `except` block.

---

With my suggested changes, your code becomes

```
while True:
    try:
        ISBN = input("Please enter a 10 digit number: ")
        print(ISBN)
        if len(ISBN)!= 10:
            print("T")
            print("That was an incorrect input.")
        else:
            ISBN = int(ISBN)
            print(ISBN)
            # do code
    except:   
        print("RRRRR")
        print("That was an incorrect input.")
```

Note however that you are catching the generic error, and it is better to catch specific `ValueError` instead.

Comment: I'm afraid it isnt desirable for me, as in the rest of the code the value is better as an integer. However i think i have solved the problem, but thank u

Comment: @user3165683 I convert it into an integer in the `else` block, if you have a re-look. `ISBN = int(ISBN)`

Comment: the problem i c whith your code is that u cannot validate that ISBN is acutaly an int when its a string

Comment: @user3165683 It validates that all right. it raises an error and goes into the `except` block, if you try to pass it a character string, since that string can't be converted to int. That happens at precisely the step `ISBN = int(ISBN)`.

Comment: i don't c how, as the try, except is looking for a string, no? or am i missing something

Comment: Has this been tested?

Comment: @user3165683 Yes, I tested this. Anyway, `try-except` is only looking for an exception, not for a string or integer.

Comment: but how does it know string is an error? p.s. i have not been sing try except long and have not tested the code myself

Comment: @user3165683 Coverting a character string to int raises the exception, if that string was non-numeric, so that's how the except block knows there is error.

Comment: ok that makes much more sense, thank u very much for your help